# Wordpress Website is Broken When Migrating to NGINX

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress, website, ubuntu-20.04

I recently migrated by WordPress website to **NGINX**, from apache2. I installed **PHP-fpm**, **PHP-cli**, and the other required PHP packages for NGINX. The site worked fine, but after clearing the cache (I use w3 total cache), the website was broken.

The overall structure of the website was intact, but almost all the website was white. Images didn't load, text was arranged in weird vertical lines, colors were wrong, and icons were missing or distorted. I was incredibly confused, as I did everything right.

I reinstalled PHP modules, reloaded PHP-fpm, and nginx, and re-set file permissions. Nope. I also noticed two other errors, in the WordPress dashboard. The first one was a message (presumably from W3 Total Cache), saying that "nginx.conf has been updated, please restart nginx".

I restarted nginx several times, and this message kept popping up. The button to dismiss the message also didn't work. The other error was that when I went into the "Site Health" tab of WordPress, it showed a message saying "JavaScript is required for site health", which led me to believe that nginx somehow wasn't loading JS (Or CSS for that matter).

At one point I even tried disabling W3, and that made the images show up, but fixed none of the other problems.

I am running Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Hard to guess. First nginx doesn't support .htaccess file. Have you done all manual configuration to mimic .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually fixed this error. The interesting thing was, one of the security headers, the content policy header, was causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
...
     #add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self';";
...
}
```

Is this what you were talking about? I was having a similar problem. Not all of the content was populating on my Wordpress 'Hello World' default and in the admin panel. I commented this out and then the content external to the site began to populate properly. I hope this helps anyone who may be facing the same issue.